# What are the possibilities to transfer data from client to server via HTTP protocol?

Tags: http, client-server, http-post, protocols, http-get

Which possibilities are provided by the HTTP protocol to transmit data and parameters from client to server?

1. Parameters included into the url (PathParams, QueryParams, MatrixParams)
2. Header parameters like CookieParams, any other custom header param
3. HTTP body whose content type is defined via the header param `Content-Type` (FormParams, and any other post data)

Is that correct and complete?

Comment: Yes. Those are your options. URI query parameters, custom app-specific headers or an entity body of your choosing. Any other questions?

Comment: Thank's for your answer! I created this question because I was not absolutely sure about. 
Another question. What should I do with questions like this, which can't be marked as accepted. Should I delete it? Or leave it as it is?

Comment: Hmm ... Not really sure. I would feel bad about supplying an answer because you kind of already did that in your question. I don't think there's any real harm it leaving the question open. Unless you just want to delete the question (which I don't see as necessary) you're fine and don't need to do anything else.